# Property HasRows em C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou fazendo um `SELECT` mysql com `inner join` dentro da minha aplicação C#

```
          MySqlCommand _comandoDados = new MySqlCommand(String.Format(
              "select EMGroot.id, EMGroot.lbs_net, EMGroot.lbs_gross_aai, EMGroot.price_brazil, sum(AAIest.qtd_venda) " +
              "from eaglemo4_eaglemotorsg.tb_products_root EMGroot " +
              "inner join eaglemo4_americai.tb_estoque AAIest " +
              "on AAIest.id_produto = EMGroot.id " +
              "where EMGroot.manupart = '" + txtManuPartInserir.Text + "'"), conexao_aai);

        MySqlDataReader Open_readerteste = _comandoDados.ExecuteReader();
        Open_readerteste.Read();
```

Após obter um Reader eu deveria jogar os dados para alguns campos, mas para que não haja erro de "DATA IS NULL", eu crio a condição `HasRows :`

```
   if(Open_readerteste.HasRows)
   {
     root_id = Open_readerteste.GetInt16(0)
     ....
   }
```

porém o resultado da condição está sempre sendo `TRUE`  mesmo quando não há 
`rows`.
Alguém saber dizer se por causa do `inner join` o `reader` sempre considera dados no comando ? ou o porque do HasRows estar sempre true ?

=================
Atualizando a minha dúvida; Descrobri que na verdade o `HasRows` está sempre `true` por causa da busca do campo `sum(AAIest.qtd_venda)`. Com a ferramente sum() o HasRows sempre vai indicar que há linhas dentro do dataReader.

Há algum jeito pra trabalhar isso ?

Comment: se for várias linhas... `while (Open_readerteste.Read())` se for uma `if (Open_readerteste.Read())`

Comment: Existe uma pergunta parecida no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348966/hasrows-property-in-mysqldatareader-c-sharp-always-return-true-value), em resumo uma das respostas sugere o uso do `MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: São varias linhas, o reader eu ja abri como mostra o código (Open_readerteste.Read();).. funciona perfeitamente quando o select encontra dados, mas quando não encontra que é onde NÃO deveria entrar na condição 'hasrows' ele está entrando e assim indicando erro de data is null.

Comment: Descobri que o problema está na busca do campo "sum(AAIest.qtd_venda)" usando o SUM() o HasRows sempre vai informar que existe linha dentro do dataReader. Se alguem souber como arrumar isso !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente incluir a cláusula having para garantir linhas somente quando SUM for maior do que zero ou algum outro contador for maior do que zero.

```
   "select EMGroot.id, EMGroot.lbs_net, EMGroot.lbs_gross_aai, EMGroot.price_brazil, sum(AAIest.qtd_venda) " +
              "from eaglemo4_eaglemotorsg.tb_products_root EMGroot " +
              "inner join eaglemo4_americai.tb_estoque AAIest " +
              "on AAIest.id_produto = EMGroot.id " +
              "where EMGroot.manupart = '" + txtManuPartInserir.Text + "'
GROUP BY EMGroot.id, EMGroot.lbs_net, EMGroot.lbs_gross_aai, EMGroot.price_brazil
HAVING sum(AAIest.qtd_venda) > 0
"
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou certinho. ...GROUP BY EMGroot.id HAVING sum(AAIest.qtd_venda) > 0